# How to "extract" files from an Android app?

Tags: applications, file-transfer

Is there a possible way to extract (I'm really sorry I can't think of a better word, my English vocabulary is not that good) files from an android app I downloaded from the app store?

Like, I got this app and there is an image I'd like to have on my PC. Is that possible? If so, how? I'm not familiar with coding and stuff.

Comment: Use any archiving software. It's just a ZIP with signature.

Comment: @iBug But where do I find the files from that particular app?

Comment: Just search the APK for that picture? It's that simple. Unless it dynamically loads it from the internet ofc...

Comment: @AndyYan But I have no idea where the apk is found on the phone or how to search for it.

Comment: Are we talking about an image that came with the app. or something you saved/created/received/whatever? In case of the former I *think* you need root to access the apps. With root you could use "titanium backup" or similar to create an archive from the app. This would save the app itself with all its data.

Comment: @confetti Yes, its an image from the app itself. Imma look into that whole root thing on youtube I guess. Is it easy to understand/do?

Comment: @Suimon if you have an application called "Backup and Restore" (or a similar title), you can extract the APK file by backing it up and then opening it as an archive.

Comment: Or you can just download the APK of the app from sites like APKPure. Since you just want to extract it for the contents (rather than installing it on the device) you don't need to care about the security/authenticity of these unofficial sources.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, APK files are ZIP archives. You can open, view and edit them, however, after editing, you need to re-signed it to be able to install. You can download APK files directly on websites like APKPure, APKMirror,... If you want to extract the APK file of the app you downloaded on the Google Play Store, you can use ADB (require computer) or ES File Explorer (directly on the phone and does not need ROOT).